# Gemoji breaks Kramdown's HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Why does [Kramdown's](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown) autolinking parser break when running it over a [gemojified](https://github.com/github/gemoji) text field?**

For `[Test](http://google.com "Test")` I'm getting:

```
<a href="http://google.com &quot;Test&quot;">Test</a>
```

instead of the expected output:

```
<a href="http://google.com" title="Test">Test</a>
```

Live app: http://runnable.com/VAL1VuMjrGFur2yx/forem-gemoji-kramdown (see the `Test` post)

`application_helper.rb`:

```
def add_emojify_and_kramdown(text)
  raw(Kramdown::Document.new(emojify(text)).to_html)
end

[...snip...]

def emojify(text)
  h(text).to_str.gsub(/:([a-z0-9\+\-_]+):/) do |match|

    if emoji = Emoji.find_by_alias($1)
      '![' + $1 + '](' + asset_path("emoji/#{emoji.image_filename}") + ')'
    else
      match
    end
  end
end
```

Some additional info:

- `raw(Kramdown::Document.new(text).to_html)` returns the expected output, but without Gemoji
- `raw(emojify(text))` doesn't change anything seeing as how `text` contains no emojis
- `raw(emojify(Kramdown::Document.new(text).to_html))` returns the expected output, but as raw HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing your `emojify` method does is `h(text)`, which HTML escapes the input, converting

```
[Test](http://google.com "Test")
```

into

```
[Test](http://google.com &quot;Test&quot;)
```

Kramdown then operates on this string, and since it no longer contains quote marks it assumes the whole contents of `(...)` is the URL, producing:

```
<a href="http://google.com &quot;Test&quot;">Test</a>
```

To get it to work you just need to drop the call to `h`: `text.gsub(...`. You’ll likely need to think about how to manage your string safety if this is external data.

Comment: Excellent catch there! Thanks so much :)

Comment: By the way man, any chance you're up for hire for a short gig?